# Python Matplotlib : savefig graphs in for loop

Tags: python, matplotlib

I try to save scatter plots created with a for loop:

```
for i in df["Canal de distribution"].unique():
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,7))
    ax.scatter(df[df["Canal de distribution"]==str(i)]["date"],df[df["Canal de distribution"]==str(i)]["Prix"],alpha=.7)
    fig.savefig("distribution données canal : {} .png".format(i), transparent=False, dpi=300,bbox_inches='tight', facecolor=(1,1,1,0))
    plt.show()
```

The graphs are created but nothing is saved. Any idea what I am missing ?

EDIT: I noticed a filed saved under the name "distribution données canal " (same as in savefig) but without any extension and just one, weird weird

Comment: Very odd - it ought to work. Can you just check if you are in the correct directory? Insert `print(os.getcwd())`.

Comment: Yes it prints the same directory

Comment: There are settings in our pc that controls whether we see the extension or not.

Comment: Still very strange. Can you try without the colon? What operating system are you using?

Comment: It just worked by removing the colon  in savefig ! I would have never figured out, is there a reason why it was preventing from saving ?

Comment: I suggested it because it was truncated at the colon, based on your report, and I'm aware that Windows uses colon as a separator for the drive letter, so was prepared to believe that it might do something odd under Windows (though I don't use Windows myself). Hence my question about OS.

Comment: So which OS _are_ you using - please can you confirm?

Comment: I was about to use the Watermark library and give you a full description of my OS (Windows) and libraries after trying but your insights was correct, thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using alaniwi's input I removed the colon from my savefig title and it worked

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10760587/13386979).  It looks like it is just rooted that colon (':') is a non-allowed character for files on some systems.  Would be nice if it gave a warning though!

Comment: Good call Tom, lesson learned I will not use it in my titles for some time!

Answer (score 0):

Change the:

```
fig.savefig("distribution données canal : {} .png".format(i), transparent=False, dpi=300,bbox_inches='tight', facecolor=(1,1,1,0))
```

To:

```
plt.savefig("distribution données canal : {} .png".format(i), transparent=False, dpi=300,bbox_inches='tight', facecolor=(1,1,1,0))
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Ann, unfortunately the result is the same: graph displayed but not saved